# Validation not working due to Date format issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written following code for validation of date

```
        var purchasedate = $("#purchasedate").val().trim();
        var formattedpurchasedate = new Date(purchasedate);
        if(checkValidDate(formattedpurchasedate.toDateString()) == false)
        {
            displayDateErrorMessage("Purchase Date");
            return false;
        }


        function checkValidDate(dateValue)
        {
                var dateFormat = getDateFormat();

                   switch(dateFormat)
                   {
                     case "d-m-Y":
                     var regex = /^((0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})$/;
                          if(dateValue.match(regex))
                              return true;
                           else
                              return false;
                     break;
                       ...
                       ..
          }
```

Now I am facing one issue i.e in input textbox, it is given value as 12/12/2016.
and in function checkValidDate it is taken as "Wed Dec 12 2017". With the result it always return false.

Please help !!!

Comment: FYI **`var formattedpurchasedate = new Date(purchasedate)`** - there is nothing being formatted here, a `Date` object is simply a datastructure and has no formatting. To be accurate better use `var parsedDate = new Date(purchasedate)`.

Comment: i m not getting you... the code seems same...

Comment: It was just an attempt at letting you know that variable names matter.

Comment: And where is `getDateFormat()` defined?

Comment: it is used to fetch date format from database... there is no issue in it

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this** :

```
if(!checkValidDate(formattedpurchasedate.toDateString()))
    {
        displayDateErrorMessage("Purchase Date");
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here. But if you want to validate the string in your input, you should just pass purchasedate to checkValidDate()

```
if(checkValidDate(purchasedate) === false)
```

because this line here:

```
var formattedpurchasedate = new Date(purchasedate);
```

It creates a Date object with the value got from input (the '12/12/2016' you mentioned in the question), and then (by this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)) this code here returns a readable string of that date:

```
formattedpurchasedate.toDateString()
```

Thus the "Wed Dec 12 2017" you state in the question. It will always be in that form because that is what a date and its toDateString method do.